# Accessing a local MySQL instance in your GAE development environment for java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am new to Google App Engine environment. We are starting a project where we are using Google Cloud SQL. For testing purpose we need to setup a local MySQL instance.
I have tried searching for the answer, but I didn't find any that helped me.

If I was to summarize my question, I am trying access a local MySQL instance in my GAE development environment using JAVA in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the MySQL connector in you App Engine SDK folder.

You can find the connector there: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/.
Then, you have to place it in this folder: `appengine-java-sdk\lib\impl`

Then you have to run a local version of MySQL (for example using EasyPHP).

Here is a sample of the code that you could use to connect to your database (singleton) :

```
public static Connection getInstance() throws Exception {
  if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
    return connection;
  }
  if (isLocalTesting) {
    //MySQL
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/YOUR_DB_NAME";
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
  } else {
    // Google Cloud SQL
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://" + instanceName + "/NAME_DB");
  }
  return connection;
}
```

And lastly:
You have to include the MySQL library in your build path as well: http://prntscr.com/124jwm

Comment: how to add .,.pls elobarate:)

Comment: i am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver exception

Comment: You have to include the library in your build path as well: http://prntscr.com/124jwm

Comment: I made a video to help others ..check out (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DIJ76RdIQw&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Yes Google should add this in the documentation, I had to look for it a bit a the beginning as well. And I think that most of the developers using Google Cloud SQL will go through this step anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse Juno and install Google App Engine SDK and plugin. There is configuration for development mysql and google cloud SQL instance. its automaticaly go to your local when development and go to cloud SQL when you deploy it.